# Why does SPACE sometimes not work with more (or less)

Tags: bash, php, less, more

Usually with `|more` I press space to get another screenful. But with some commands space just does nothing, and I need to actually keep doing SPACE-ENTER to scroll forward a screen at a time. Both `more` and `less` behave the same.

On this machine this command shows both behaviours:

```
php -i |more;tree -A |more
```

With PHP I need to press ENTER after each space; with `tree` I just press SPACE and it scrolls.

I've tried a few tricks, such as `2>&1` and using bash, but no luck, e.g.

```
bash -c "php -i 2>&1;tree -A" | more
```

Joining the commands like that means SPACE-ENTER is needed for the whole output. So I'm wondering if PHP is outputting some control character that upsets `more`?

I've tried another machine, over SSH, and `php -i` does not have this behaviour.

(I have `LESS` set to `-FRX`. However I've cleared that variable and the behaviour is the same.)

This is just a minor irritant, so I'm not going to start pulling the two systems apart looking for the difference... just wondered if it rang a bell with anyone.

---

**UPDATE (Nov 26 2014) **

Someone contacted me to say they can reproduce this with:

> Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
>    PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.21 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 19:13:13)

My current system is now Mint 17 (PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5) and I do not have this behaviour. It is also fine on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (over SSH).

I do have the problem on Ubuntu 11.10 (over SSH). PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10

It is fine on Ubuntu 12.10 (over SSH). PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4

So it looks like a bug that might've been fixed between Ubuntu 11.x and 12.x, or between php 5.3 and 5.4?  (If no-one can come up with any more evidence, I'll post that as a self-answer in a few weeks time.)

Comment: To debug this we'll likely need the version of PHP, more, less and Bash + the OS you're using. I cannot reproduce this issue and I've tried it on several OS'es that I have at my disposal.

Comment: @slm So you think it is a bug? I was guessing it was a feature being triggered somehow?

Comment: Not necessarily, I think it might be a configuration issue w/in your shell, but need to start at the top in debugging the issue further. If I know the versions I can try replicating them on my side and work my way up to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

The `more` and `less` pagers are run with their standard input connected to the output of the previous elements in the command pipe. They have to explicitly open the controlling TTY device in order to provide their paging UI. The controlling TTY is also the standard input of the first element of the pipeline.

If the command being paged is reading from the TTY and/or interfering with it (changing TTY settings), you get strange behaviors like this.

For a crazy "trip", try something like:

```
$ vi file | less
```

Here is how we can make `less` require <kbd>Enter</kbd> for something that is normally a hot key:

```
(echo foo; sleep 1; stty icanon; bar) | less
```

If you wait for `bar` to appear, and consequently `less`'s prompt, then you won't be able to quit `less` by just typing <kbd>q</kbd>. You will have to type <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. The program has messed with the TTY by putting it into canonical input processing mode: line-at-a-time input, rather than character-at-a-time.

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> quickly during the `sleep 1`, you will instantly get the `:` prompt from `less` and will be able to quit with <kbd>q</kbd> since the `stty` never had a chance to execute.

If the command being paged does something with the TTY immediately on startup, then there is a race condition: which one will mess with the TTY first: the `less` program (in order to set up character-at-a-time input) or the program being paged? This is why there is a `sleep` in the above test; to let `less` win the race.

It does sound as if `php` (either itself or something loaded and executed by `php`) might have been doing something funny with the TTY, and that was fixed.